# Method to copy data from another sheet where date range (time on project) exists within another date range (month)

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm currently loading in some resource data into one sheet (summary)  to populate another sheet (weekly), based upon whether or not there was planned activity for that resource in the month in question. From that data, and what activity was, I'm then trying to establish the projected hours for each resource and then record the actuals, to track the performance of the team.

I'm currently using this formula (cell B8) to pull the data from Summary sheet, based upon the month indicated in G6:

```
=QUERY(Weekly!B7:K99,"select E,B,C,I,J,D,H,G where I >= date '"&TEXT(G6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

I'm also using this formula, in N8, to establish whether the days in the month had allocated time, and if so, at what percentage:

```
=QUERY(Weekly!B7:K99,"select E,B,C,I,J,D,H,G where I >= date '"&TEXT(G6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

While this seems to work for November, it breaks down for other months. I've tried multiple variations to try and get it to work, but I can't seem to be able to establish whether the month has time in it, and then to accurately record it.

Any ideas as to how to get this to work?

Here's a version of the sheet I'm working with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1epCnivFZvxjPNBdNK82Np0aPfFN1LbIXHrrbgnQEQus/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean "it breaks down for other months" trying to look at your spreadsheet but having a problem understanding what exactly your problem is/what you want the outcome to be? Can I have a specific cell/number or example that is wrong and what it should be?

Comment: Sure! So when I change the month (on double click) in cell G7, it should then change the cells populated in column B to M, based upon the fact that they have time allocated to them in that month. Subsequently, the cells that are populated in columns N and greater (alternate rows) should then change dependent upon the allocations that have changed in B to M.

Comment: It's effectively a burn report. I'm trying to see what hours were allocated (in the other sheet) per month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=query(arrayformula({Weekly!B7:K99,text(Weekly!I7:I99,"yyyy-mm-dd")}), "Select Col4,Col1,Col2,Col8,Col9,Col3,Col7,Col6 where Col11>='" & TEXT(G6,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'",0)

where Col1:Col9 = B:J
```